# php nohup not working

Tags: php

I used the pear system daemon class, that basically allows me to create a daemon that runs as user 1000 and group 1000.

It then uses the php exec function to execute the following code:

```
nohup php merge.php 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!
```

for some reason merge.php does not start executing. I have started thinking its a permission problem...

What can I do to fix this?

When I run the daemon as root, merge.php gets executed ... so it is definately a permissions problem.

merge.php is owned by webmaster and group apache.

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing more - what permissions are set on merge.php? Does removing the nohup help (your title implies that that might be the cause)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried without the `echo` at the end and also witout the `1 > /dev/null` and replaced this with the simple `>/dev/null`.

Also you could try making a script

```
#!/bin/sh

exec php merge.php
```

And then

```
nohup <script name> >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```